# How to transform the Gatsby Image component into a figure

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm looking to extend the `gatsby-image` component to make it a semantically correct `figure` and add a `<figcaption>` inside of it.

There is a `Tag` prop that allows it to render as a `figure`, but I couldn't figure out how to add the child.

Here is what I tried.

```js
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Figure = (props) => {
  return (
    <Img Tag="figure" fluid={props.fluid} alt={props.alt}>
        <figcaption>This is the caption of my amazing image.</figcaption>
    </Img>
  )
}

export default Figure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do there is to pass a `children` to `<Img>` component which is external, so you are not able to handle it. In other words, `<Img>` tag will have inside a `<figcaption>` and you don't know if it accepts `children` to render (it doesn't).

Another approach that may work for you is to wrap this configuration inside a custom figure tag. Such as:

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"

const Figure = (props) => {
  return (
    <figure>
      <Img fluid={props.fluid} alt={props.alt}/>
      <figcaption>This is the caption of my amazing image.</figcaption>
    </figure>
  )
}

export default Figure
```

The `Tag` prop is intended to change the wrapper, set by default as a `<div>` but doesn't allow you to add a caption despite being a `<figure>`.

Comment: Thanks, I wound up doing it as you suggested. Hopefully, it is good enough for search engines. Since I'm not an expert I was wondering if I could accomplish it by inheritance or some other obscure means, but it might overcomplicate the issue.